# Finding the order of a subgroup $G$ in $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question I seem to be stuck at.

The question states that $G$ is the smallest subgroup of $S_4$ that contains the following set:

$$\lbrace(1,2,3), (1,3,4), (1,2,4), (2,3,4), (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3)\rbrace$$

I need to find the order of G and its elements and if $G$ is a known subgroup of $S_4$. There is also given a hint to use Lagrange's theorem to identify the possible orders of $G$.

First thing I did was find the orders of the elements in the set to be the following (in order):

$$3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2$$

Next I found the order of $S_4$ to be $4! = 24$

Which means that from Lagrange's theorem the possible orders of $G$ are:
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24$$

Since there are a minimum of $7$ elements in $G$ I restricted the possible orders to:
$$8, 12, 24$$

This is where I am stuck at. Is what I have done up till now correct? What would be the next course of action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** By Lagrange Theorem, the order of any element in $G$ divides the order of $G$.

Since there is an element of order $3$, there are only two possibilities for $|G|$.

**Hint 2** All the permutations you listed are **even**.

Comment: So restricting the possible orders down to 8, 12, and 24 was valid then? I just want to make sure I didn't do that wrong.

Comment: @jdminer Yes, that was a good first step.

Comment: I've tried looking in my textbook for any information on even/odd permutations that might help me determining is G is of order 12 or 24 but can't seem to find a helpful theorem.

Comment: @jdminer $A_4$ is a subgroup of order 12 in $S_4$ ;)

Comment: It is impossible to get an odd permutation by multiplying even permutations. Hence, their name even/odd. Since half of the permutations are even and the other half are odd, at most your group is of order 12. That should complete the reasoning of the answer along with N.S. hints.

Comment: I think what was confusing me was why couldnt G include all of $S_4$ but the question asks for the smallest subgroup that contains the set which must be 12 since they're all even. Is this reasoning correct? @ReverseFlow

Comment: Yes! The "smallest" condition prevents it, as you explain. :D